# How can I access data sent in a post request in Django?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-templates

I have a form that is supposed to create a new 'Quote' record in Django. A 'Quote' requires a BookID for a foreign key.

This is my form

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'quotes:createQuote' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <section>
        <label for="q_text">Quote Text</label>
        <input type="text" name="text" id="q_text" placeholder="Enter a Quote" style="padding-left:3px"> <br>

        <label for="q_book">Book ID</label>
        <input type="text" name="bookID" id="q_book" placeholder="Enter Book ID" style="padding-left:3px"> <br>

        <label for="q_disp">Display Quote Now?</label>
        <input type="radio" name="display" id="q_disp" value="True"> True 
        <input type="radio" name="display" value ="False">False <br>
        <button value="submit">Submit</button>
    </section>
</form>
```

And this is the method that it is targeting

```
def createQuote(request):
    #b = get_object_or_404(Book, pk=request.bookID)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('quotes:index'))
```

Somewhere in that request argument I assume there is some sort of field that contains the bookID the user will pass in on the form. How do I get at that information?

Bonus points for anyone who can tell me some way I can visualise data like I might with `console.log(some.collection)` in Javascript

Comment: This is well covered in the tutorial and expanded in the documentation on the request object.

Comment: You're right, there is an example of this. I didn't notice that before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if request.method == "POST":
     book_id = request.POST['book_id']
```

Assuming you're sure it's in there. Otherwise you'll need to verify/provide a default value like you would for a normal python dictionary.

As for visualising the data, do you mean printing it to the console? In which case if you're running the django runserver you can just do `print some_data`. If you want it formatted a little nicer, you can use pretty print:

```
import pprint
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter()
pp.pprint(some_data)
```

Comment: I am using the django runserver. I think I have misunderstood something though. Can I actually write a print inside a file that is controlling the POST like my quotes/views.py or do I have to do use the manage.py shell or something? I've never seen any of my prints work but that is possibly due to the redirect clearing the console.

Comment: With the standard runserver, `print` statements should go straight to the console. Whether it's getting lost in request spam or you've customised something I don't know. To be honest I tend not to use print statements, and either use `assert False, some_data` to give me a django error screen with the variable I want to display on it, or use [pdb](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html).